# Get HTTPS GET request with headers in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday

I have the following curl command that works fine:

```
curl "https://api.multisafepay.com/v1/json/gateways" -X GET -H "api_key: e983177756a109e87aa5edbe05e0xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

When I try to do the same from within Rails (I tried with HTTP and with Faraday I always get back a response that contains:

> "error_info\": \"Invalid API key\"

This is the command I do for Faraday:

```
conn = Faraday.new 'https://api.multisafepay.com/v1/json/'
conn.headers = {'api_key' => 'e983177756a109e87aa5edbe05e0xxxxxxxxxxxx'}
conn.get 'gateways'
```

What is the difference with the Curl command that is giving a correct result set?

Edit: debugging into Faraday shows me that in this method:

```
def run_request(method, url, body, headers)
```

headers are nil?  I'm continuing my search why this is.

Comment: I can't see any difference. Are you sure that its not a simple typo somewhere?

Comment: Yes 100% sure.  When I include it the api_key as a query param it works though.  I find it a bit strange they accept both query params and headers...  Here I see an example with query param: https://www.multisafepay.com/developers/  in the API docs they speak about headers.  Curl is definitely using headers and it works there.  Are there things Curls does by default that need to be set in Faraday?

Comment: Try `conn = Faraday.new('https://api.multisafepay.com/v1/json/', headers: 
{ 'api_key' => 'e983177756a109e87aa5edbe05e0xxxxxxxxxxxx' })`. Although I don't get why the `headers=` setter would not work. Allowing both a http_header and query parameter is not that uncommon. Its just sloppy that the documention is does not list both.

Comment: Same result unfortunately. Very strange. What I don't get is why Curl is working.  I'll use query params for this, don't want to continue wasting time on this.

Comment: try conn.headers["api_key"]: "<yourkey>"

Comment: @colincr I tried:
conn.headers["api_key"] = "<yourkey>" with same result.

Comment: Try passing a block to it like: 
    conn = Faraday.new do |f|
      req.url = "url"
      req.headers["api_key"] = <your key>
    end
    conn.get

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're giving Faraday the right URL. Try something like this

```
   conn = Faraday.new do |f|
     f.headers['api_token'] = <yourkey>
     f.request :url_encoded
   end
   resp = conn.get('https://api.multisafepay.com/v1/json/gateways')
```

Comment: I don't seem to get content in the response with this.  I'm getting this back:  => #<Faraday::Response:0x007fc155d90198 @on_complete_callbacks=[], @env=#<Faraday::Env @method=:get @url=#<URI::HTTPS https://api.multisafepay.com/v1/json/gateways> @request=#<Faraday::RequestOptions (empty)> @request_headers={"api_token"=>"e983177756a109e87aa5edbe05eXXXXXXXXXX", "User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.1"} @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)>>>

Comment: What does resp.body return?

Comment: resp.body returns nil

Answer (score 0):

```
  require 'rest-client'
  require 'json'

  response = RestClient.get("https://api.multisafepay.com/v1/json/gateways", 
    {'api_key' => 'e983177756a109e87aa5edbe05e0xxxxxxxxxxxx'}
  )

  puts JSON.parse(response, { symbolize_names: true })

  #just in case try this one for header
  #{:content_type => :json, :accept => :json, :api_key => 'e983177756a109e87aa5edbe05e0xxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

Comment: I tried it like this, got exactly the same result as with Faraday: "error_info": "Invalid API key".  Unbelievable...  I checked once again and it's the exact same key in Curl that does work.  I also tried with the extra json params.

Comment: Yup, see my last comment: I also tried with the extra json params.  I sent a mail to multisafepay maybe they can shed some light on this.  I got it working completely with query params though I'm very curious what's causing this.